# pygame 2.0.0 installation error on m1 macOS Big Sur

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, apple-m1

I used `python3 -m pip install pygame==2.0.0` via non-rosetta terminal and got these errors:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/1q/4hfh5j_d715b0vm49lql6vl80000gn/T/pip-install-cqq2oily/pygame_3a311b7a5339480eb6bae08f88ff3fe6/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/1q/4hfh5j_d715b0vm49lql6vl80000gn/T/pip-install-cqq2oily/pygame_3a311b7a5339480eb6bae08f88ff3fe6/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/1q/4hfh5j_d715b0vm49lql6vl80000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ig7pjjbc
     cwd: /private/var/folders/1q/4hfh5j_d715b0vm49lql6vl80000gn/T/pip-install-cqq2oily/pygame_3a311b7a5339480eb6bae08f88ff3fe6/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame==2.0.0
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame==2.0.0
```

My homebrew,  pip3 are all up to date.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried 2.0.1?

Comment: When you type `python3 -m pip install pygame`, what pygame version is installed?

Comment: pygame 1.9.6 is installed. I've tried to --upgrade pygame too but a long error also appears :(

Answer (score 0):

I already had the same problem: the [`pip` module](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) only detected a [`pygame`](https://www.pygame.org) version older than 2.0.0.

It always installed pygame 1.9.6.

---

Maybe you should:

### 1. Upgrade pip

I don't know how `pip` works, but I updated it by typing

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then, when I typed again

```
python3 -m pip install pygame
```

`pip` downloaded the 2.0.1 version of `pygame` correctly.

---

### 2. Check your internet connection

Of course the modules come from Internet.